# jquery element sometimes doesn't stop on hover out

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make 6 cd images to move 35px and rotate 45deg at the same time when I over my mouse on them.
It works, but sometimes when I leave the hover area, the animation doesn't stop, sometimes it repeats 6 or 7 times before stoping... and I don't have a clue why, this is the only query I've in my file, what should I do?

Thanks

css

```
#cd1 {
    left: 0px;
}
#cd2 {
    left: 40px;
}
#cd3 {
    left: 80px;
}
#cd4 {
    left: 120px;
}
#cd5 {
    left: 160px;
}
#cd6 {
    left: 200px;
}
```

html

```
<body>
    <div id="cd6"></div>
    <div id="cd5"></div>
    <div id="cd4"></div>
    <div id="cd3"></div>
    <div id="cd2"></div>
    <div id="cd1"></div>
</body>
```

jquery

```
var cds = ['#cd1', '#cd2', '#cd3', '#cd4', '#cd5', '#cd6'];
var pos_init = ['0', '40', '80', '120', '160', '200'];
$(cds).each(function(i) {
    $(cds[i]).hover(
        function() {
            var esquerda = parseInt(pos_init[i]);
            $(this).animate({left: (esquerda + 35) + 'px'}, 'slow');
            $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(45deg)'});
        },
        function() {
            var esquerda = parseInt(pos_init[i]);
            $(this).animate({left: (esquerda) + 'px'}, 'slow');
            $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: @Starx; jsfiddle.net :-)

Comment: I did create a fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/Pluda/FUqUL/  so everyone can see and test the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function before your animation.

```
var cds = ['#cd1', '#cd2', '#cd3', '#cd4', '#cd5', '#cd6'];
var pos_init = ['0', '40', '80', '120', '160', '200'];
$(cds).each(function(i) {
    $(cds[i]).hover(
        function() {
            var esquerda = parseInt(pos_init[i],10);
            $(this).stop().animate({left: (esquerda + 35) + 'px'}, 'slow');
            $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(45deg)'});
        },
        function() {
            var esquerda = parseInt(pos_init[i]);
            $(this).stop().animate({left: (esquerda) + 'px'}, 'slow');
            $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        }
    );
});​
```

Comment: This approach seemed to work nicely in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr5aP/) I created for this. Albeit tricky to land on the values very easily

Comment: adding the stop was what was missing. Thanks, now just need to have a nice rotation speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cds = ['#cd1', '#cd2', '#cd3', '#cd4', '#cd5', '#cd6'];
var pos_init = ['0', '40', '80', '120', '160', '200'];
$(cds).each(function(i) {
        $(cds[i]).hover(function() {
            var esquerda = parseInt(pos_init[i]);
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({left: (esquerda + 35) + 'px'}, 'slow');
            $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(45deg)'});
        },
        function() {
            var esquerda = parseInt(pos_init[i]);
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({left: (esquerda) + 'px'}, 'slow');
            $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        }
    );
});​
```